# Magento and database max_user_connections error

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7

Is there a way of monitoring in Magento what modules make connections to the database? Recently I encountered that my website the following error in reports:

`SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User magento_db_user already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections`

My hosting allows having 10 active connections at once, so the hosting shouldn't be the problem here, right? The number of users that visit my website at once is also not that high.

I would have to know a way of monitoring/logging what modules try to connect to the database, so I can react, maybe improving or disabling some of them. Is there a way to do it in Magento? The only monitoring methods I was able to find on the Internet are for databases themselves, but my hosting doesn't allow tinkering with the db.

Thanks in advance for any ideas on how to deal with this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@boruch - enabling persistent connections, huh??

@Bartosz Górski -if you dont have access to my.cnf file and if your hosting provider limiting your database operations, you better find another one. for god sake, this is your shop, your business. today you can get any hosting you like, unlimited.

Comment: This was the simplest solution, but it was also the best one. The active connections cap was just too small, so I had to move the website to another hosting provider. Thanks!

Comment: How about this? Our site has been live for a few months. We've had over 100 visitors at once and no problem. This last week though, our dev server started showing this error. Only our 6 person team has access to the dev server so it was just 6 connections at most? It can't be the active connections cap in this case, it must be new code but I can't find the bottle neck!

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling persistent connections in your server (if you can).
Also you can use an event observer to get all connections (like model_load_before)
But the module could be a bit complex.

Maybe try disabling modules one at a time and see if this returns? :)

Comment: It turned out it was a hosting issue - the active connections cap was just too low. But thanks for the ideas anyway!

Comment: @BartoszGórski What was the number of `max_user_connections` that you ended up setting?

Comment: @CodeFinity can't remember what it was back then as it was over 7 years ago. So I can only tell you that now, when working locally, I have this set to 0 and remote servers on which my Magento 2 code ends up also have this set to 0.

Comment: @BartoszGórski Tx. I might try that...although it seems like it would be 'bad' to have 0 `user_connections` - like nobody would be able to connect and do _queries. _

Comment: @CodeFinity sorry for a late answer. The 0 value is for no limit, which means that the limit is what your dbms can handle.